# Why is the Wiener Algebra closed under pointwise multiplication of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, banach-algebras, wiener-algebra

I want to understand the proof given on the wikipedia page for the Wiener Algebra $A(\mathbb{T})$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra)) that $A(\mathbb{T})$ is closed under multiplication. We have
$$ A(\mathbb{T}) = \{f:\mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{R}: \|f\| < \infty \} $$
with norm $\| \cdot \|$ given by $$  \| f\| = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat f(n)|,$$
where $\hat f(n)$ is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$.
The proof given on the wikipedia page is as follows: For $f,g\in A(\mathbb{T})$, we have
\begin{align}
f(t)g(t) & = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(m)e^{imt}\,\cdot\,\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{g}(n)e^{int} \\
& = \sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(m)\hat{g}(n)e^{i(m+n)t} \\
& = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \left\{ \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n-m)\hat{g}(m) \right\}e^{int}
.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\|fg\| &= 
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \left| \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n-m)\hat{g}(m) \right| \\ &\leq \sum_{m} |\hat{f}(m)| \sum_n |\hat{g}(n)| \qquad\qquad (*)\\ &= 
\|f\| \, \|g\|
\end{align}

The line that I don't understand is indicated by $(*)$. It is not clear to me why we can say that $$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \left| \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n-m)\hat{g}(m) \right|  \leq \sum_{m} |\hat{f}(m)| \sum_n |\hat{g}(n)|. $$ Why does this inequality hold? Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Many thanks to @almosteverywhere for their answer. Using the discrete version of Young's convolution inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \left| \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n-m)\hat{g}(m) \right|  =
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \left| \widehat{f * g}(n) \right| = 
\| \widehat{f * g} \|_{\ell^1} \leq 
\| \hat{f} \|_{\ell^1}\| \hat{g} \|_{\ell^1} =
\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(m)| \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{g}(n)|.
\end{align}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple proof:
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \Big| \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z} \hat f(n-m) \hat g(m) \Big | \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z} | \hat f(n-m) | . | \hat g(m) | = \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z} | \hat g(m) | \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} | \hat f(n-m) | $$
where you just need to switch the order of summation for the last part

Answer (score 3):

They have used a discrete version of Young's convolution inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality#Generalizations.

More precisely, given an (locally compact) abelian group (i.e. $\mathbb{Z},+$) equipped with its bi-invariant Haar measure (i.e. the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}$), we have
$$
\lVert f* g \rVert_{L^1(\mathbb{Z})} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{L^1(\mathbb{Z})} \lVert g \rVert_{L^1(\mathbb{Z})} \, ,
$$
with the convolution defined the way you would expect it to be and integrable functions $f,g: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$.